# How to fill the area under a 3d parametric curve with variable height?

Tags: pgfplots, 3d, fillbetween, clip

I have a scalar field f(x,y)=1-x and a curve C given as the graph of g(x)=4x(1-x). My goal is to fill the area between the curve (x,g(x),f(x,g(x))) and its projection (x,g(x),0). Up to this point, I'm only able to draw some (many) support lines, but this keeps looking weird. I'm looking for a solution, that uses fillbetween or clip or maybe a plot of the resulting parametric surface y=4x(1-x) with x between 0 and 1 and z between 0 and 1-x.

The picture serves as a graphical interpretation of a standard line integral of a scalar field along a parametrized curve.

My ideas so far:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
        declare function={f(\x,\y)=1-\x;},
        declare function={g(\x)=4*\x*(1-\x);},
        view={60}{30},
        enlargelimits=false,
        ticks=none
    ]
    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,0.001,...,1}{
        \draw[gray] (#1,{g(#1)},{f(#1,#1)}) -- (#1,{g(#1)},0);
    }
    \addplot3[
        name path=B,
        variable=t,
        mesh,
        gray,
        domain=0:1,
        domain y=0:1,
    ] (t,{g(t)},0);
    \addplot3[
        name path=A,
        variable=t,
        mesh,
        domain=0:1,
        domain y=0:1,
    ] (t,{g(t)},{f(t,{g(t)})}); %\closedcycle;
    %\addplot3[blue!50] fill between[of=B and A];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The loop is not satisfying as it allows the coordinate axis/box lines to shine through. Any ideas, how to accomplish this goal?

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative, `Asymptote` version:

```
//
// param3d.asy
// 
//   to get a standalone param3d.png, run
// asy -f png -render=4 param3d.asy
// 
import graph3;
size(200,0);
currentlight.background=paleyellow+opacity(0.0);
currentprojection=orthographic(camera=(65,-36,25),up=Z,target=(0,0,0),zoom=1);

triple fs1(pair t){
  real u=t.x, v=t.y;
  return (u,4*u*(1-u),(1-u)*(1-v));
}
surface s1=surface(fs1,(0,0),(1,1),nu=100,nv=100);
draw(s1,orange+opacity(0.8),meshpen=nullpen,render(merge=true));
draw(surface((0,0,0)--(1,0,0)--(1,1,0)--(0,1,0)--cycle),lightblue+thick());
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit late but I'm surprised that there is still no Ti*k*Z solution to this. So there is a very simple one.

In isometric perspective is very easy to find the tangent points between a vertical line that joins the given curve and its xy-plane projection (a parabola). I did by hand using [this method](https://www.geogebra.org/m/ttppm3rJ) (see below).

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}

% isometric perspective
\pgfmathsetmacro\xx{1/sqrt(2)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\xy{1/sqrt(6)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\zz{sqrt(2/3)}
\tikzset
{%
  isometric/.style={x={(-\xx cm,-\xy cm)},y={(\xx cm,-\xy cm)},z={(0 cm,\zz cm)}},
  surface/.style={draw=red,left color=#1!20,right color=#1!80,fill opacity=0.5}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[isometric,scale=4,line join=round]
% tangent point (easy to obtain with some geometry)
\coordinate (T) at (3/8,15/16,5/8);
% xy plane
\fill[green!20] (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0) -- (1,1,0) -- (0,1,0) -- cycle;
% axes
\draw[latex-latex] (1.25,0,0) node [below] {$x$} -- (0,0,0) -- (0,1.25,0) node [below] {$y$};
\draw[-latex] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1.25) node [above] {$z$};
% surface
\draw[surface=gray] plot [domain=0:3/8,samples=16] (\x,{4*\x*(1-\x)},0)    -- (T) --
                    plot [domain=3/8:0,samples=16] (\x,{4*\x*(1-\x)},1-\x) -- cycle;
\draw[surface=red]  plot [domain=1:3/8,samples=26] (\x,{4*\x*(1-\x)},0)    -- (T) --
                    plot [domain=3/8:1,samples=26] (\x,{4*\x*(1-\x)},1-\x) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**A little explanation:**

1. First we write the parabola equation in the form `(x-x_v)^2=2p(y-y_v)` and we obtain the vertex `V(v_x,v_y)`. In this example is `V(1/2,1)`.
2. From the vertex we obtain the focus `F(v_x,v_y+p/2)` and the directrix `y=v_y-p/2`. In our parabola they are `F(1/2,15/16)` and `y=17/16`.
3. We draw (or find the equation of) a line from `F` perpendicular to the tangent direction (so the line must be horizontal w.r.t. 2d axes).
4. We find `P(3/8,17/16)`, the intersection between the previous line and the directrix.
5. Now `M(9/16,1)` is the midpoint between `F` and `P`.
6. The tangent line passes through `M` and is vertical.
7. Finally the tangent point in the parabola `T(3/8,15/16)` is the intersection between this curve and the tangent line. And the tangent point in the parametric curve is above `T` so it's a 3d point `(3/8,15/16,z)` that must satisfy the curve equations (another intersection).

[image]